# static unsigned hashStr (const RWCString& str)

Tags: c++, string, hash

I was going through my applications core code and i found this function:

```
//======================================================
// Hash functions needed for the different Dictionaries
//------------------------------------------------------

static unsigned hashStr (const RWCString& str)
{
    return (str.hash () );
}
```

when i googled it i found the following:

```
unsigned
hash(caseCompare = RWCString::exact) const;
```

*Returns a suitable hash value. If caseCompare is RWCString::ignoreCase then this function will be incompatible with MBCS strings.*

but i could hardly understand this!

could anybody please Help me in understanding the concept behind this?
may be an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know what an hash function is. Otherwise there is a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for that.

(in general an hash function is a function that from a (big) domain of data (lets say normally a sequence of bytes of any length) returns an element of a smaller domain (lets say a sequence of 32..256 bits) (with 32 bits you have an `unsigned`)

To quote from the wiki:

> A hash function is any algorithm or subroutine that maps large data sets of variable length, called keys, to smaller data sets of a fixed length. For example, a person's name, having a variable length, could be hashed to a single integer. The values returned by a hash function are called hash values, hash codes, hash sums, checksums or simply hashes.

`MBCS` is an old coding used to codify Chinese, Japanese... Let's say it's an ancestor of `UTF8` and it works in a similar manner (some characters are codified in 1 byte, some in 2 bytes and so on.

The comment about MBCS is because probably `RWCString` doesn't have collation tables for multi byte strings (tables that tell it how to make a character uppercase, and to do other operations, like sorting...).

Probably the hash function, when called with `RWCString::ignoreCase` does:

```
return mystring.toUpper().hash(RWCString::exact)
```

so it converts the string to upper case and calculate the hash. Without the collation tables, it can't do the `toUpper()` part.

Comment: Just one remark: As far as I'm aware, MBCS nowadays refers to any kind of multibyte encoding, including UTF-8, GB-2312 etc.

Comment: @MrLister http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx : Multibyte character sets (MBCSs) are an alternative to Unicode for supporting character sets, like Japanese and Chinese, that cannot be represented in a single byte.

Comment: @MrLister If you look at the wiki, the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set redirects to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding

Comment: Hm, you're right about the Microsoft page, but the wikipedia page does mention UTF-8 and UTF-16 as examples of MBCS encodings.

Comment: @MrLister I'll say that the wiki gives examples of multibyte character sets (and puts them under "Variable-width encodings"), not of MBCS, where the acronym is something more "specialized" and "different"